# Adding templated arguments to a command in bash

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci

I am setting up a new project with multiple extensions. My goal is to track the code coverage for all extensions. Extensions live in subdirectories of the directory extensions and have multiple source folders. The number of extensions in my project is not final. So I will most certainly add one or more. Consider a structure like this:

- extensions

  - extension A

    - src
    - testsrc
    - web

      - src
      - testsrc
  - extension B

    - ...

All extensions follow the same structure. I am using the coverage-jdk11 job as described here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html#java-and-kotlin-examples

Now instead of

```
python /opt/cover2cover.py target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml 
          src/main/java 
          > target/site/cobertura.xml
```

I need to add multiple src directories, which is supported. So my current version looks like this:

```
python /opt/cover2cover.py jacoco.xml
          extensions/extensionA/src
          extensions/extensionA/testsrc
          extensions/extensionA/web/src
          extensions/extensionA/web/testsrc
          > cobertura.xml
```

But this one obviously only supports extensionA. My idea is to iterate through the subdirectories of the extensions directory and create multiple arguments for each subdirectory. But I have no idea how to do this in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it working with the following command:

```
find extensions -type d -maxdepth 3 -regex "^extensions/.*/\(testsrc\|src\)$" | xargs -t python /opt/cover2cover.py hybris/log/junit/jacoco.xml > hybris/log/junit/cobertura.xml
```